# MS_POSITIONING Is Not a Valid Attribute of Elements BODY and DIv

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, html, coding-style, refactoring

We have a lot of legacy ASPX pages in our solution. Now we want to fix the code styling (bring it to the HTML5 standard) and generally clean the code on these ASPX pages. One of the issued I ran into is the `ms_positioning` attribute. It appears a lot in the `<body>` and `<div>` elements. Visual Studio 2010 shows this warning:

`Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'ms_positioning' is not a valid attribute of element 'div'.`

**Question:**

1. Should I try to fix this warning or should I just leave
   `ms_positioning` attribute alone?
2. Is there another way to achieve the same functionality without `ms_positioning` attribute (I use both `ms_positioning="GridLayout"` and `ms_positioning="FlowLayout"` values) and in accordance with HTML5 standard?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that  `ms_positioning` is not longer available in newer versions of visual studio (as seen in [this](http://forums.asp.net/t/924638.aspx/1) link).

However there are two ways to achieve the same functionality:

1. Go to Format menu, and then select position. And then select **absolute**

or

1. Go to **Tools menu**, and then select **options**. go to **HTML Designer**, then **CSS Styling** and then check **Change positioning to absolute for controls using Toolbox, paste or drag and drop**

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't test it myself, but the solution looks reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where the `ms_positioning` comes from, but maybe you can try setting the conformance mode in web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <xhtmlConformance mode="Strict"/>
</system.web>
```

Whatever ASP.net does with this set should work.